# gitlab-ci. Проблема со сборкой docker compose в shell с использованием gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, shell, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Встала задача написать автоматическую сборку и публикацию проекта в ***docker compose*** с последующим запуском. Для этого я выполнил следующие шаги:

1. В gitlab, запущенном на моём сервере создал, зарегистрировал и запустил *2 раннера* (один **docker**, второй **shell**).

[image: runner]

- настроил **config.toml** для этих ранеров, после чего он приобрёл следующий вид:

> ```
> concurrent = 1
> check_interval = 0
> shutdown_timeout = 0
>
> [session_server]
>   session_timeout = 1800
>
> [[runners]]
>   name = "docker-runner"
>   url = "http://gitlab.my.host123"
>   id = 50
>   token = "TOKEN-hidden"
>   token_obtained_at = 2023-07-27T12:16:48Z
>   token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
>   executor = "docker"
>   [runners.docker]
>     tls_verify = false
>     image = "docker:stable"
>     privileged = true
>     disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
>     oom_kill_disable = false
>     disable_cache = false
>     volumes = ["/cache"]
>     shm_size = 0
>
> [[runners]]
>   name = "shell"
>   url = "http://gitlab.my.host123"
>   id = 51
>   token = "TOKEN-hidden"
>   token_obtained_at = 2023-07-27T12:17:46Z
>   token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
>   executor = "shell"
>   [runners.custom_build_dir]
>     enabled = true
>   [runners.cache]
>     MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
> ```

2. На сервере с **gitlab** выдал пользователю **gitlab-runner** права на доступ к docker с помощью команды:

> usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner

в `/etc/sudoers`

3. Из папки `/home/gitlab-runner/` удалил файлы `.bashrc, .profile, .bash_logout`
4. Написал `gitlab-ci.yml` со следующим содержимым:

> 

```
.docker:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: docker


variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  extends:
    - .docker
  script:
    - docker pull api.$CONTAINER_NAME:latest || true
    - >
      docker build
      --pull
      --cache-from api.my.host123/$CONTAINER_NAME:latest
      --build-arg ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Prod"
      --tag api.my.host123/$CONTAINER_NAME:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
      --tag api.my.host123/$CONTAINER_NAME:latest
      ./MyProject.WebApi
  only:
    - main
    - production

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - mkdir -p ~/deploy
    - cp -i docker-compose.production.yml ~/deploy/docker-compose.yml
    - docker compose down --remove-orphans
    - docker compose pull
    - docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
  only:
    - main
    - production
```

5. В проекте на **asp.net** создал **Dockerfile**

> 

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 7155

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:7155

RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject.WebApi.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.WebApi.dll"]
```

и два файла **docker-compose**:

- **docker-compose.production.yml**

> 

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  webapi_myproject:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
    container_name: webapi_myproject
    ports:
      - "7155:7155"
    expose:
      - "7155"
    restart:
      unless-stopped
```

- и **docker-compose.yml**

> 

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  webapi_myproject:
    build:
      context: ./MyProject.WebApi
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: webapi_myproject
    ports:
      - "7155:7155"
    expose:
      - "7155"
    restart:
      unless-stopped
```

После публикации и запуска **docker-runner'ов** я получаю следующий результат:

[image: result]

В **build** всё выглядит действительно хорошо и образ проекта создаётся на диске сервера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот в **deploy**...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API
> version: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2375): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /version (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f612d4ea560>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3]
> Temporary failure in name resolution'))

Если я добавляю в **gitlab-ci.yml**

> before_script: docker version

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - shell
  before_script:
    - docker version
  script:
    - mkdir -p ~/deploy
    - cp -i docker-compose.production.yml ~/deploy/docker-compose.yml
    - docker compose down --remove-orphans
    - docker compose pull
    - docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
  only:
    - main
    - production
```

То вижу уже следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/version": dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving

Если все команды из **deploy** я выполняю на сервере в консоли, то контейнер создаётся и всё работает так, как мне и нужно. Здесь же я подозреваю, что проблема в докере, но знаний и опыта не хватает понять причину. Буду благодарен за любую помощь и наводки в решении данной проблемы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы с `error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/version": dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving`оказалось очевидным. Проблема была в том, что **variables** находился поверх всех блоков и его действие распространялось в том числе и на тэг ***shell*** (в **deploy**). Достаточно было **variables** спрятать в в блок ***build*** и всё заработало. И ещё изменил скрипты, чтобы это работало логично.

> **gitlab-ci.yml**

```
.docker:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: docker

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  extends:
    - .docker
  #Перенос variables в build
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  script:
    - docker build
      --cache-from api.sh.forged.host/$CONTAINER_NAME:latest
      --build-arg ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Prod"
      --tag api.sh.forged.host/$CONTAINER_NAME:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
      --tag api.sh.forged.host/$CONTAINER_NAME:latest
      ./SmartHome.WebApi
  only:
    - main
    - production

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - docker compose down --remove-orphans
    - docker compose rm -f
    - docker compose build
    - docker compose pull
    - docker compose up -d
  only:
    - main
    - production
```